# How to recover wifi interface `wlo1`?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, interface

After I installed something, my interface device is disappeared. Before I installed, I had:

```bsh
$ iwconfig

lo       ...

enp2s0   ...

wlo1     ...
```

Now it is only:

```bsh
$ iwconfig 

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Now I can't see any wifi. How to recover my interface device or install another?

**Edit**

I'm using HP laptop, Ubuntu 16.04

I remember that I'd installed `linux-generic` package.

When I run:

```bsh
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dkms status

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:81ec]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Sanji2 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:038f Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b008 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Comment: What did you install?  or change?  Providing us with more details (if you don't remember, explore your `history` or logs for reminder) allows us to provide you with better help.  Even your release of Ubuntu would be a start.

Comment: I had installed `linux-generic`. I'm using HP laptop

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: Have you tried using a different kernel (ie. selecting another at your `grub` boot-manager screen), ie. different to what I assume is 4.4.0.143.151 (or do you have HWE (*hardware enablement stack*) enabled and thus it installed 4.15.0.46.48?).  Can you please provide `uname -a`

Comment: It looks like you delete wifi driver.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dkms status`

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31, I've edited my question

Comment: One more thing, I'm running 2 Ubuntu on my computer. I'd lost wifi interface on my old ubuntu, and now I tried booting to the old, it works. I dont understand what is happening

Comment: What about results for `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31, `SecureBoot disabled`

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed and now it's working :P

I've done step by step as the installation instruction at https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new to install new driver wifi.